# Antlr parse Tree node coordinates?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I use Antlr4 4.9.2

I have a requirement to perform multiple passes of the same parse tree at different stages of my analysis. Some of the files my application handles are very large, therefore I'd like to be able to avoid keeping the parse tree in memory, and be able to regenerate a different parse tree instance each time. So far so good.

My challenge is that I need a way to (a) compare nodes and (b) quickly access nodes that works with different instances of equivalent parse trees.

For example the following pseudo-code generates two separate instances of a parse tree that represent the same file (therefore the parse trees and their nodes are equivalent)

```
ParseTree parseTree1 = parse(myFile, myGrammar)
ParseTree parseTree2 = parse(myFile, myGrammar)
```

Since `myFile` and `myGrammar` are the same, both `parseTree1` and `parseTree2` are equivalent, however are different instances and don't satisfy `Objects.equals()`

In ANTLR, how do I represent the coordinates C of a node in such a way that:

- C(node1) = C(node2) if the nodes are equivalent
- I can access C(parseTree1) or C(parseTree2) without having to visit the parse trees - so I can quickly position myself on the same node, for any instance of the parsetree

Comment: What does `C(parseTree1)` signify? Accessing an arbitrary node in the parse tree?

Comment: Yes that’s what I meant, sorry if my writing wasn’t clear. 

I am basically looking to have something that is invariant between instances and that lets me a) access nodes quickly and b) figure out if two nodes of equivalent parse trees are the same (i.e should satisfy equals).

Comment: Isn't C() just a hash code? You can define it to be whatever you want, based on invariants such as line/column number, text, token type, token range, depth of parse tree, an XPath string representing the node within a parse tree, etc. You would need to visit the tree once to precompute the hash values for all nodes. To find it in other instances, use a multi-map. Take care in using XPath.findAll() for finding a node. The XPath engine *is* a tree walker. I ported a far more capable XPath2 engine to C# for Antlr tree/grammar refactoring, but I haven't had time to backport it to Java.

Comment: Yes, what you describe is the approach I have taken so far.  My invariant is:


public class NodeInvariant {
private final Optional<String> start;
private final Optional<String> stop;
private final Integer hashCode;
private final Integer ruleIndex;
private final Integer depth;
private final Integer childCount;
}


It works, but it feels suboptimal and I want to make sure I am not missing a trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ANTLR4's XPath](https://github.com/mike-lischke/antlr4/blob/master/doc/tree-matching.md#using-xpath-to-identify-parse-tree-node-sets) implementation to directly access nodes in a given parse tree path. Here's how I get all query expressions in MySQL code, after parsing:

```js
const expressions = XPath.findAll(tree, "/query/simpleStatement//queryExpression", this.parser);
```

Comment: This sounds interesting, thank you Mike! I see how I can get an XPath string to locate a node, but given a node in the parse tree, how can I get the XPath string that points to it? Any ideas?

Comment: The path is nothing more but a concatenation of the parser rules that lead to a specific node. If I understand you correctly, you want to compare specific nodes at the same parse position, in two different parse trees. Inspect the grammar to learn which path leads to that node.

Comment: I have made some progress in generating XPath coordinates from a node, however I can't find a way to select a specific child in a rule something like 
/parent/child[2] isn't accepted. Any ideas on how to select a specific child within my ANTLR XPath expression?

Comment: Probably not the full XPath spec is implemented, but you can select the parent node, pick a child index and continue with a sub path, if necessary.

Comment: Great idea, thanks Mike for the pointer!

Comment: @LorenzoFrattini Please accept my answer if it is useful for you. Upvote it also, if you think it is worth it.